# Getting a RuntimeError while running chatbot using Pytorch and NLTK library (python engineer tutorial code)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, nlp, nltk

I have written this line "device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')" still getting the following errror. I have provided my all code that i written till now please with this.

RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! (when checking argument for argument mat1 in method wrapper_addmm)

#### Train.py File

```
import json
from nltk_utils import tokenize, stem, bag_of_words
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from model import NeuralNet

with open('intents.json', 'r') as f:
    intents = json.load(f)


all_words = []
tags = []
xy = []

for intent in intents['intents']:
    tag = intent['tag']
    tags.append(tag)
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        w = tokenize(pattern)
        all_words.extend(w)
        xy.append((w, tag))

ignore_words = ['?', '!', '.', ',']
all_words = [stem(w) for w in all_words if w not in ignore_words]
all_words = sorted(set(all_words))
tags = sorted(set(tags))



x_train = []
y_train = []

for (pattern_sentence, tag) in xy:
    bag = bag_of_words(pattern_sentence, all_words) 
    x_train.append(bag)

    label = tags.index(tag)
    y_train.append(label) # CrossEntropyLoss


x_train = np.array(x_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)


class ChatDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.n_samples = len(x_train)
        self.x_data = x_train
        self.y_data = y_train

    # dataset[idx]
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.x_data[index], self.y_data[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.n_samples

batch_size = 8
hidden_size = 8
output_size = len(tags)
input_size = len(x_train[0])
learning_rate = 0.001
num_epochs = 1000

print(input_size, len(all_words))
print(output_size, tags)


dataset = ChatDataset()
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)    

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

model = NeuralNet(input_size, hidden_size, output_size).to(device)


criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for(words, labels) in train_loader:
        words =  words.to(device)
        labels = labels.type(torch.LongTensor) # <----- Here (Casting)
        labels = labels.to(device)

        # forward
        outputs = model(words)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

        # backward and optimizer step
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    if (epoch + 1) % 100 == 0:
        print(f'epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}, loss={loss.item():.4f}')

print(f'final loss: {loss.item():.4f}')

data = {
    "model_state" : model.state_dict(),
    "input_size" : input_size,
    "output_size" : output_size,
    "hidden_size" : hidden_size,
    "all_words" : all_words,
    "tags" : tags,
}


FILE = "data.pth"
torch.save(data, FILE)

print(f'training complete , file saved to {FILE}')
```

## chat.py file

```
import random
import json
import torch 
from model import NeuralNet
from nltk_utils import bag_of_words, tokenize


device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
# device = torch.device('cuda')


with open('intents.json', 'r') as f:
    intents = json.load(f)

FILE = 'data.pth'
data = torch.load(FILE)
input_size = data["input_size"]
hidden_size = data["hidden_size"]
output_size = data["output_size"]
all_words = data["all_words"]
tags = data["tags"]
model_state = data["model_state"]

model = NeuralNet(input_size, hidden_size, output_size).to(device)
model.load_state_dict(model_state)
model.eval()


bot_name = 'Sam'
print("Let's chat: type 'quit' to exit")
while True:
    sentence = input('You: ')
    if sentence == "Quit":
        break

    sentence = tokenize(sentence)
    X = bag_of_words(sentence, all_words)
    X = X.reshape(1, X.shape[0])
    X = torch.from_numpy(X)

    output = model(X)
    _, predicted = torch.max(output, dim=1)
    tag = tags[predicted.item()]

    probs = torch.softmax(output, dim=1)
    prob = probs[0][predicted.item()]


    if prob.item() > 0.75:
        for intent in intents["intents"]:
            if tag == intent["tag"]:
                print(f"{bot_name}: {random.choice(intent['responses'])}")
    else:
        print(f"{bot_name}: I do not understand...:(")
```

After running the chat.py. while chatbot is trying to send their response then it giving the runtime error.
I should get the response from chatbot. but getting the following error

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBs2j.png)